# After publishing, my Umbraco admin panel did not show in IE9. But it appear in FF and Chrome browsers

Tags: asp.net, web, umbraco, publishing-site

After publishing, my Umbraco admin panel did not show in IE9. But it appear in FF and Chrome browsers.

Note: Before publishing website, I run it from Visual Studio 2012 and I observed that everything was Okay.

Can anyone help me?

[image: in IE9]
[image: in Firefox]

Comment: Is that the problem related to ClientDependency?

Comment: What version of umbraco are you using?

Comment: @Inrbob: Umbraco version is "4.11.1"

Comment: @Jahan Have you published it to an internet URL or an intranet URL? Do you have any JS errors? Do you have "Compatibility View" turned on in IE?

Comment: First port of call: re-upload in case of 0-byte files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A disappearing tree is often related to an error in the `Treedataservice.ashx` call.

If you use F12 developer tools in IE9 you should be able to get the URL for this web service call from the Network tab, it will look something like this:

> http://your-domain.local/umbraco/webservices/TreeDataService.ashx?rnd=d4859dc821714624be368bdafb1dd1d9&id=-1&treeType=content&contextMenu=true&isDialog=false&rnd2=89.4

Then when you call the web-service url from the browser direct you should be able to see the error that is returned and therefore ascertain the exact issue.

I've tested 4.11.1 with IE9 and the tree works correctly, therefore it suggests the issue is with your instance.

If the above web service is functioning correctly (it should return JSON), then it may be worth checking the other webservice calls, such as `TreeClientService.asmx` for errors.

In most cases checking these webservices will reveal the actual issue which is causing the tree to not render.